# Вырезать часть карты api yandex 2.1

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В песочнице есть данный пример по вырезанию части карты:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_mask

Как корректно сделать подобное для РФ? Понятно что iso3166 надо ставить RU и изменить restrictMapArea, чтобы вместилась страна. Но в остальном карта как-то долго грузится для РФ и многоугольник закрывает часть субъектов. Может кто подскажет в чем причина, может координаты многоугольника изменить как-то иначе.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lbomv7j/

ymaps.ready(function () {

```
var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [50, 15],
    zoom: 2,
    type: 'yandex#hybrid',
    controls: ['zoomControl']
}, {
    // Ограничим область карты.
    //restrictMapArea: [[48, 11], [51.5, 20]]
});

map.controls.get('zoomControl').options.set({size: 'small'});

// Загрузим регионы.
ymaps.borders.load('001', {
    lang: 'ru',
    quality: 2
}).then(function (result) {

    // Создадим многоугольник, который будет скрывать весь мир, кроме заданной страны.
    var background = new ymaps.Polygon([
        [
            [85, -179.99],
            [85, 179.99],
            [-85, 179.99],
            [-85, -179.99],
            [85, -179.99]
        ]
    ], {}, {
        fillColor: '#ffffff',
        strokeWidth: 0,
        // Для того чтобы полигон отобразился на весь мир, нам нужно поменять
        // алгоритм пересчета координат геометрии в пиксельные координаты.
        coordRendering: 'straightPath'
    });

    // Добавим многоугольник на карту.
    map.geoObjects.add(background);

    // Найдём страну по её iso коду.
    var region = result.features.filter(function (feature) { return feature.properties.iso3166 == 'RU'; })[0];

    // Добавим координаты этой страны в полигон, который накрывает весь мир.
    // В полигоне образуется полость, через которую будет видно заданную страну.
    var masks = region.geometry.coordinates;
    masks.forEach(function(mask){
        background.geometry.insert(1, mask);
    });
})
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сдвинуть немного координаты и тогда Россия поместится в заданный полигон

```
[
            [85, -100],
            [85, 0],
            [85, 100],
            [85, 180],
            [85, -110],
            [-85, -110],
            [-85, 180],
            [-85, 100],
            [-85, 0],
            [-85, -100],
            [85, -100]
        ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2x0cuksw/

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!